# Beginner MEANjs Application - Using Yo Scaffold VS creating from scratch

Tags: web, mean-stack, yo

I'm new to building web applications using the MEAN stack. That being said, I started building applications using Ruby on Rails.

I've noticed many similarities, but also many differences using MEANjs.

Obviously when using the Rails framework, you use the CLI command - Rails new (app). Builds your whole app skeleton.

Now when creating applications using MEANjs, i've seen many tutorials build files from scratch, but also some use the YOMEN generator to scaffold whole skeleton applications (like "rails new (app)").

The problem i'm confused about is there are so many more files included when using YOMEN compared to "rails new".

Simply asked, should I be creating single files to build my MEAN applications? Or should I be scaffolding (since i'm somewhat familiar with  scaffold-ed applications)?

What are the big differences in creating an application from scratch rather than 'yo meanjs'?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience i like to build from the scratch. But if you need a kickstart  project it would be good to use yeomen. yo creates basic modules for server and client side and gives you a platform to start with. Yo gives commands to create CRUD modules as well as for angular controllers also.I personally prefer to build from the scratch.

Comment: Thanks, i've been trying to create apps from scratch. I think it's better than just scaffolding and trying to digest everything you DON'T know.